# Prevent Stock Decrease if customer in a certain Customer Group places the order?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, sales-order, stock

If the customer is in a certain **customer group category**, what is the most efficient way to prevent stock decrease once the order is placed?

I want the quantity to remain unchanged only for some customers after they place an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an observer for `sales_order_save_after` and try this:

**Observer.php**

```
public function salesOrderSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order   = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $groupId = $order->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId();
    # adjust group ID
    if ($groupId == '1') {
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $product   = $item->getProduct();
            $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
            $stockItem->setQty($stockItem->getQty());
            $stockItem->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice workaround. Will try to create observer.php in local directory and test it out.